# Descriptive statistics: a metric of the "lumpiness" of numeric vector

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, entropy, binning

I have three datasets of continuous data. Is there a convenient metric for the "binnedness" of the data? How "lumpy" it is?

I'd like a single number to allow me to distinguish between these three datasets (generated by the R code below).

[image]

````
library(tidyverse)

sds <- c(0, 2, 6)

dataset_1 <-
  c(
    rnorm(25, mean = 20, sd = sds[1]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 40, sd = sds[1]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 60, sd = sds[1]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 80, sd = sds[1])
    )


dataset_2 <-
  c(
    rnorm(25, mean = 20, sd = sds[2]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 40, sd = sds[2]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 60, sd = sds[2]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 80, sd = sds[2])
  )


dataset_3 <-
  c(
    rnorm(25, mean = 20, sd = sds[3]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 40, sd = sds[3]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 60, sd = sds[3]),
    rnorm(25, mean = 80, sd = sds[3])
  )


tibble(
  dataset_1,
  dataset_2,
  dataset_3
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "dataset", values_to = "x") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,  fill = dataset)) + geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~dataset, ncol = 1) 

```
````

Comment: I would look into entropy measures. Some kind of empirical continuous entropy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite a single numbers, but you could do a quick cluster analysis and look at the within- and between-cluster sums of squares.

From the output of `kmeans(dataset_1, centers = 4, nstart = 25)` (and similarly for the other two datasets), we have:

```
Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 0 0 0 0
 (between_SS / total_SS = 100.0 %)
```

```
Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 127.60912  76.78191 121.07307  69.15073
 (between_SS / total_SS =  99.2 %)
```

```
Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 593.5224 722.0721 481.3305 449.7612
 (between_SS / total_SS =  95.5 %)
```